# Multiple concurrent X/Wayland users on different monitors?

Tags: kde, xrandr

Scenario: I'm running KDE5 on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed with separate "work" and "personal" accounts. I'm logging into these concurrently on TTY7 and TTY8 and can switch between them with C-M-F7/8. On a single screen this is fine, but with multiple monitors, it would be nice to be able to have one screen mapped to each session.

Is this possible?

Comment: Multiseat is the answer. X: [X.org docs](https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/Multiseat/), [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg_multiseat). Wayland have in [theory](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM4MzA), but haven’t found any doc/tutorial.

Comment: I feel like that's too hard-coded and wouldn't survive a dock/undock cycle of a laptop. Actually a better solution just occurred to me, but it'll need to be a new question.